# Representation of direct product $G\times H$ on tensor product

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory, semi-simple-rings

Let $G$ and $H$ by finite groups.
Let $V$ and $U$ be irreducible representations of $G$ and $H$, respectively.

When the ground field is $\mathbb{C}$, I know how to show that $V\otimes U$ is an irreducible representation of $G\times H$ (using character theory).

What about other ground fields? Is $V\otimes U$ guaranteed to be an irreducible rep of $G\times H$ if the ground field is $F$ and $\operatorname{char}F\nmid|G|$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. For example, let $G$ be cyclic of order $3$. Then $G$ has an ireducible module $U$ of dimension $2$ over ${\mathbb Q}$. But $U \otimes U$ is not irreducible for $G \times G$; it decomposes into two $2$-dimensional modules.

Comment: That's great! I guess that $U$ is given by a rotation in $2\pi/3$ degrees. How can I see this decomposition of $U\otimes U$?

Comment: And another question: Is your example still valid if we replace $\mathbb{Q}$ by $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: Yes, $U$ is irreducible over ${\mathbb R}$,so the example is still valid.

Comment: Since the image of any irreducible representation of an abelian group is cyclic, representations of $G \times G$ can have degree at most $2$, so $U \otimes U$ cannot be irreducible. You could also  find the decomposition by looking at the complex characters.